# Gulp was working but then stopped

Tags: gulp

I am stuck, I have been trying to learn gulp and I am slowly putting together a gulpfile.

I got to a point testing as I went along and everything was fine. A few days later I returned to continue with it and now it doesn't work. I have no clue whats wrong.

my gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),

// required for CSS and LESS
less = require('gulp-less');
prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

// required for JS
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),

rename = require("gulp-rename");

var paths = {
  src : {
    less       : '.assets/less/styles.less',
    js_main    : '.assets/scripts/main.js',
    js_plugins : '.assets/scripts/plugins/*.js',
    img        : ''
  },
  dest : {
    css : './public/assets/css/',
    js  : './public/assets/js/',
    img : ''
  }
};

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src( paths.src.less )
  .pipe( less() )
  .pipe( prefix("last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7") )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.css ) )
  .pipe( rename('styles.min.js') )
  .pipe( minifyCSS() )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.css ) );
 });

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src( paths.src.js_main )
  .pipe( concat('main.js') )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.js ) )
  .pipe( rename('main.min.js') )
  .pipe( uglify() )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.js ) );
});

gulp.task('plugins', function() {
  gulp.src( paths.src.js_plugins )
  .pipe( concat('plugins.js') )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.js ) )
  .pipe( rename('plugins.min.js') )
  .pipe( uglify() )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.js ) );
});
```

So this was working when I stopped working on it but when I ran gulp styles in terminal days later i get this:

```
$ gulp styles
[gulp] Using gulpfile ~/projects/boilerplates/website-boilerplate/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'styles'...
[gulp] Finished 'styles' after 3.8 ms
```

so far I have tried to delete the installed node modules and re install them. I have also tried installing gulp globally again.

Would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like gulp is running to me.  What do you mean it isn't working?

One thing that's wrong with your gulpfile is you *need* to return the streams, like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src( paths.src.less )
//^^^^^^
```

Otherwise gulp won't know when a particular task is finished.  This [(or another async option)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support) needs to be done for every task.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have made the change and its still not working.

What I mean by not working is it shows in terminal that the task has run, starts and finishes and displays the time taken for it to run but nothing actually happens.

So when I run styles, its meant to compile my less, prefix it then minify it but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Maybe your file listing is incorrect? Try inserting `gulp-debug` into your stream to see what (if any) files are being processed.  It's also possible that `gulp.less` is crashing with a typo.

Comment: i still get the sam result with gulp-debug. So I started a new project and worked through a tutorial from scratch and its still doesnt work. it prints out Starting 'styles'..., Finished 'styles' after 4 ms but doesnt do anything

Comment: @MurraySmith I couldn't figure it out, after much trail and error I moved over to Grunt. If you find a solution please let me know.

Comment: I did find a solution, but for me it was an issue with concat and uglify on my JS files

Comment: @user45038 more specifically, it was an issue with the default `gulp-concat` not picking up the end of a stream, so I switched to `gulp-continuous-concat`

Comment: anyone else has an answer to this?